# Brushless motor not turning

Tags: batteries, brushless-dc-motor, torque, drone

I'am trying to build a drone. Therefore I bought some [brushless DC motors](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/4pcs-A2212-Brushless-Motor-1000KV-H366-for-RC-F450-F550-Aircraft-Plane-Multi-copter-Brushless-Outrunner/1971991736.html)

This is the only specs I have for the motors :

```
- Max Efficiency Current: 4-10A (>75%)
- Current Capacity: 12A/60s
- No Load Current @ 10V: 0.5A
- No. Of Cells: 2-3 Li-Poly
- Motor Dimensions: Φ27.5 x 30mm
- Shaft Diameter: Φ3.17mm
- Weight: 48g
```

The problem is that when I try to power them, they won't spin.
I'm using a 9V battery.

Any idea why ? I think the battery might be to weak.

Also, I'm a french programmer willing to expend his knowledge, so I have very little skills in electricity and electronics in general. If you could explain like you would to a child that would be a plus. :)

Comment: Are you aware that a BLDC is requiring a little more than just a battery to turn? Isn't the number of wires coming out of it puzzling you?

Comment: yup, you need an electronic commutator.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Has I said, no knowledge in electronics. Can you provide a real answer ?

Comment: See @JonRB's comment. Call it commutator, driver or controller. It's too broad for a real answer.

Comment: @JonRB I also try to make them spin with an arduino and a [motor shield](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Freeshipping-L293D-motor-control-shield-motor-drive-expansion-board-FOR-Arduino-motor-shield-best-price/818263787.html). Could that be the electronic commutator ?

Comment: @artonge No. It is not suitable for BLDCs.

Comment: As a general advice, *research* before buying stuff :)

Comment: I did, but obviously not enough ! Can you advise an electronic commutator that would be compatible with the arduino motor shield ?

Comment: Sorry, can't help. Start [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-motor-selection-guide/brushless-dc-motor-control)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These BLDC motors require a controller for each (which is quite complex, but can be purchased as a module), which is called an [ESC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_speed_control) (Electronic Speed Control) in this domain.

They often look something like this:

[image]

There are more parts on the back of the PCB, and typically it would have some heat shrink over the board.

The three wires at the bottom go to the 3-phase BLDC motor, the red and black wires at the top go to the battery (heavy current- **more than a 9V battery can supply**) and the other three thin wires are for control. The connector, voltage and signaling is similar to that of a conventional RC servo- a TTL-level pulse of width 1-2ms, repeated at some tens of Hz to a couple hundred Hz. Narrow pulses are for slow, wide for fast motor speed command.